# Parametric equations of parallelogram

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Imagine the parallelogram with vertices $(1,0,0),(2,1,1),(0,2,2),(1,3,3)$. 
How do we find parametric equations for it?

I found the Cartesian equations of its four sides

$$y=z=2-2x$$
$$y=z=5-2x$$
$$y=z=x+2$$
$$y=z=x-1$$

How do I go from these to equations $x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)$?

Comment: you can use equations of the form like $$x=[x_0,y_0,z_0]+t[x_A,y_A,z_A]$$ and $t$ is a real parameter

Comment: I need equations in $u,v$ since I want to do a surface integral over the parallelogram.

Comment: Or better, $x=[x_0,y_0,z_0]+t([x_1,y_1,z_1]-[x_0,y_0,z_0])$ with $0<=t<=1$

Comment: what do you mean with $$u,v$$?

Comment: Use $u=x$ and $v=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for a point internal to a (planar) parallelogram as yours
$$
\mathbf{x} = u\,\mathbf{s}_\mathbf{1}  + v\,\mathbf{s}_\mathbf{2} \quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant u,v \leqslant 1} \right.
$$
where $\mathbf{s}_\mathbf{1}$ and $\mathbf{s}_\mathbf{2}$ are the vectors corresponding to two concurrent sides, and $\mathbf{x} $ the position vector vs. the common point